# Do every class in Kotlin extends Any class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am writing an extension function for `RecyclerView` to set `LayoutManager` and `Adapter` to the `RecyclerView`.The function should accept any Adapter class which is Extending from `RecyclerView.Adapter<Any>` as like in Java we use `RecyclerView.Adapter<?>`.How can we acheive this in Kotlin?.

```
internal fun <T : RecyclerView.Adapter<Any>> RecyclerView.initAndSetAdapter(context: Context, adapter: T) {
    this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    this.setHasFixedSize(true)
    this.adapter = adapter
}
```

The function call to this method is not compiling due to Invalid Type.But if i change `Any` to `*` then it is working properly.

```
internal fun <T : RecyclerView.Adapter<*>> RecyclerView.initAndSetAdapter(context: Context, adapter: T) {
    this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    this.setHasFixedSize(true)
    this.adapter = adapter
}
```

Why method call is not compiling with `Any` class?.Do every class in Kotlin extends `Any` class like Java `Object` class?.

Comment: Try using `<T : RecyclerView.Adapter<*>>` although actually isn't that supposed to be a subclass of `ViewHolder`?

Comment: Both versions compiles on my side. What is your kotlin version?

Comment: Method will compile.Try to call the method by passing an adapter instance.Then it won't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation: 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html

`Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass.`

That being said - the class that adapter takes needs to extend from ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

The type of RecyclerView.Adapter has to be a ViewHolder or ViewHolder subclass. This is defined in the class and you can’t expand its scope to Any or Object. That would defeat the purpose of generics. By using the star projection it automatically uses the largest bounds defined by the class `<out ViewHolder>/<in Nothing>`.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView.Adapter<Any>` is equivalent to Java `RecyclerView.Adapter<Object>` which is not at all the same as `RecyclerView.Adapter<?>`. In particular, if you have something like

```
class AnAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeType>
```

then `AnAdapter` is a subtype of `RecyclerView.Adapter<*>` (`?` in Java) and *not* a subtype of `RecyclerView.Adapter<Any>` (`Object`). So you can't pass an instance of `AnAdapter` to a method expecting a subtype of `RecyclerView.Adapter<Any>`.

Please see [Variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) in Kotlin documentation.